# Erro file_put_contents() failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel

Boa tarde!

Acredito ter deletado de forma incorreta uma das pastas `STORAGE` e agora meu projeto esta com o erro a seguir

> file_put_contents(/Users/claudio/Desktop/laravel/projeto/storage/framework/sessions/cQfSldUOUGFEcnL3Z8INxCExQQW3s13Nb2kp5AT6): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Já busquei pela internet e mandaram limpar cache do `config.php` do `bootstrap/cache/` remover o arquivo etc.

Nada aparentemente tem funcionado.
Alguém já cometeu este erro ou sabe como fixar que não seja instalando um novo projeto?

Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consegui fixar o projeto baixando a pasta do meu repositório e fazendo tudo que já tinha pesquisado antes

primeiro baixei a pasta e coloquei no lugar da `storage` que havia deletado.

rodei um `php artisan config:cache` e apliquei `chmod -R 775 storage` na storage da raiz e da public

nao consigo dizer ao certo o que foi que resolveu, sei que tudo junto solucionou.

Answer (score 1):

Recrie as pastas.
Na raiz do seu projeto, crie a estrutura:

```
storage/  
storage/app
storage/framework/cache  
storage/framework/session
storage/framework/views
storage/framework/testing
storage/logs
```

Comment: fiz o processo mas infelizmente nao funcionou amigo, há o problema.

Comment: tem um truque q talvez resolva. uma vez fiz isso e tive q copiar um dos arquivos dentro da pasta: /Users/claudio/Desktop/laravel/projeto/storage/framework/sessions/ e pegar o arquivo q está ausente: cQfSldUOUGFEcnL3Z8INxCExQQW3s13Nb2kp5AT6 e colar no nome do que eu copiei e funcionou.